# JS star rating system

Tags: javascript, html, mean, rating

```
var num_stars_løn = 0
var num_stars_team = 0
var num_stars_trivsel = 0

function add_rating(num_rating, section) {
    if (section == "løn"){
        num_stars_løn = num_rating;
        document.getElementById("num_stars_løn").value = num_rating;
    }
    else if (section == "teambuilding"){
        num_stars_team = num_rating;
        document.getElementById("num_stars_team").value = num_rating;
    }
    else if (section == "trivsel") {
        num_stars_trivsel = num_rating;
        document.getElementById("num_stars_trivsel").value = num_rating;
    }

    for(var i = 1; i < num_rating + 1; i++) {
        var section_id =  section + " " + i
        document.getElementById(section_id).innerHTML = "&#x2605;"
    }
    if (num_rating < 5){
        for(var i = 5; i > num_rating; i--) {
            var section_id =  section + " " + i
            document.getElementById(section_id).innerHTML = "&#x2606;"
        }
    }


    if (num_stars_team > 0 && num_stars_løn > 0 && num_stars_trivsel > 0){
        show_mean_rating();
    }
}

function show_mean_rating() {
    var mean = document.getElementById("num_stars_løn").value + 
        document.getElementById("num_stars_team").value + 
        document.getElementById("num_stars_trivsel").value;
    document.getElementById("mean_rating").innerText = "Gennemsnitlig rating: " + (mean/3).toFixed(2);
}
```

HTML

I have made a star rating system for some topics (3 in total) using JavaScript and HTML. Do one of you know how to calculate the average/mean of how many stars each topic received? So not the three topics all together, but the mean per topic of clicks/stars.

Right now it finds the mean of all 15 stars in total. (each topic has 5 stars) But it is supposed to calculate the mean for each individual topic. I’m thinking maybe something with a counter for each meeting every time a user clicks on the stars, but I am not sure. And then maybe divide the stars with amount of votes/stars given

Comment: If you want to find the mean of each category, you need to store all the data for a particular category in an array and then do the sum of the whole array and divide it by the length of the array to find the mean.

Comment: Your setup only accounts for voting for one user. If you want a mean for multiple votes for the same topic, you need to store the results for multiple users. This depends on your conditions (ie database, single page voting, web sockets, etc). Also, you should create id's with spaces since they are invalid (ie `section + " " + i` should be `section + i` or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

To get the mean of each section, you would need to capture each vote with a counter (can be stored in state or in plain text with # of votes) and divide the sum of all of the votes by the number of votes.

This can be done with an array of votes with each vote being added to an array every time a user clicks a rating, adding all the values in the array together, and dividing it by array.length.

Comment: cant get it to work, not sure how to iplement this... :((((

Comment: Are you capturing the amount of votes each section gets?

Comment: Here is a potential solution once you figure out how to capture and divide each vote by section; https://codepen.io/aidanchase/pen/PowQjYg